# Is shipping an 80% lower to someone in Washington Illegal

Tags: united-states, texas, washington, firearms, shipping

I was apart of a conversation where one person who lives in the state of Washington wanted someone who lives in Texas to buy a glock `80% lower` for them and ship it to them in Texas. To me, this sounds like a really bad idea and I alerted the Texan about my concerns. I tried looking up the legality on it and it seems like it might technically be legal because the ATF doesn't consider an 80% lower a firearm until it's been milled. Can someone please explain to me if this would be a legal transaction, or should I continue to urge these two to back out.

edit: An `80% lower` is described as "An 80 lower is an unfinished lower - "80" meaning it is 80% percent complete. To turn an 80% lower into a 100% lower you have to mill out the fire control group"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, [Washington State Senate Bill 5061](http://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/biennium/2019-20/Pdf/Bills/Senate%20Bills/5061.pdf) seeks to block certain "untracable" firearms without a serial number.  This relates in part to "3D printable" guns, but the act of milling of a 80% lower (in Washington) could be a violation, if and when it passes. But [it appears the bill hasn't been made a law yet](https://app.leg.wa.gov/billsummary?BillNumber=5061&Year=2019)... Is Washington specific news this issue what drives the question?

Federally, the [ATF web site](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/are-%E2%80%9C80%E2%80%9D-or-%E2%80%9Cunfinished%E2%80%9D-receivers-illegal) says:

> **Receiver blanks that do not meet the definition of a "firearm" are not subject to regulation under the GCA. The ATF has long held that items such as receiver blanks, "castings" or "machined bodies" in which the fire-control cavity area is completely solid and un-machined have not reached the "stage of manufacture" which would result in the classification of a firearm per the GCA.**

But this gets a bit technical.   For further risk mitigation, the Texan could mitigate any risk related to both Federal and Washington state law by shipping it to a federal firearms licensee (FFL) in Washington as if it were a firearm, [per ATM instructions which say](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/whom-may-unlicensed-person-transfer-firearms-under-gca) (in part):

> **Generally, for a person to lawfully transfer a firearm to an unlicensed person who resides out of State, the firearm must be shipped to a Federal Firearms Licensee (FFL) within the recipient’s State of residence. He or she may then receive the firearm from the FFL upon completion of an ATF Form 4473 and a NICS background check.**

That FFL is then responsible for ensuring the transaction properly conducted in the state of Washington, including federal and state requirements.   The FFL I contacted only charged $25.00 (plus collecting the state sales tax).   [Form 4473](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/atf-form-4473-firearms-transaction-record-revisions) was easy enough; only about one page for me to fill out.  Of course, I've got a clean record, so going through channels isn't a problem for me, it took less than an hour.

The FFL confirmed for me that it wasn't necessary for something like an antique musket, which legally isn't a firearm by the federal defeinitions.   In my case the sender was a nervous "trust" lawyer who wasn't sure, hired yet another lawyer to advise him.  The FFL didn't charge me anything for receiving that musket.

Comment: The FFL isn't needed for the lower 80, please see the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes @putvi, I acknowledge that in the first quote, but it might get complicated for someone who isn't experienced in this.   Using the FFL is simply a way of mitigating any risk to the sender.   The links in my answer are to the official ATF web site, rather than  a commercial cite.

Comment: I've added some notes about why proposed legislation in Washington might complicate matters, but it seems questionable to me if it could ever apply in Texas.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This looks like to covers the situation and the correct means for the transaction.

Answer (score -4):

It's legal to ship a gun provided you follow all other laws.

I took your question to mean can you ship a gun, but if you are asking if you can ship an 80 lower without a license, the answer is yes.

https://www.80percentarms.com/80-lowers/

Comment: Incorrect - one must ship to an FFL. Any shipper who does not have an FFL is considered to be an unlicensed person. Unlicensed persons must ship modern firearms to a licensed FFL dealer only. If the buyer is not licensed, they will need to make arrangements to have the item shipped to a licensed FFL dealer in their state. ATF.gov

Comment: Hence why I said as long as you follow all other laws.

Comment: Your answer is you can ship a gun except for the law  that says you can’t that you don’t mention ?

Comment: My answer is that you can ship it as long as you follow that law and all others as I said.

Comment: I think @GeorgeWhite doesn't understand what a 80% lower is, the definition can git tricky for someone who isn't a gunsmith.

Comment: @Burt_Harris honestly when I saw "blanks" in your answer I thought you meant like bullet blanks. I'm sorry.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite - Under federal law, a person may ship a firearm to themself in another state. https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/may-nonlicensee-ship-firearms-interstate-his-or-her-use-hunting-or-other-lawful-activity

Comment: @Dave D - thanks, I didn't know that. But it is not the OPs case.